# failed to get disk format of disk /dev/nvme1n1: exit status 127

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, disk-volume

**What happened?**
I had an old AWS EKS kubernetes cluster, running 1.21, so i decided to upgrade it.
While upgrading to 1.23 if not mistaken i was prompted that i need to install the AWS EBS CSI driver, so i did through the AWS Console --> Clusters --> Addons (latest version)

After installing the plugin however, a redis deployment, that requires a gp2 volume can't be created with the following error :

**kubectl describe pod redis-b9d65796c-psdkw**

`Warning  FailedMount             2s (x5 over 9s)  kubelet                  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-aed078f4-658f-4656-90c0-44bb8b347e2a" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not format "/dev/nvme1n1" and mount it at "/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/ebs.csi.aws.com/e252b2dda3ccd485b35aa3719d2930464320c09504b4a63d2d029e7e64d42c99/globalmount": failed to get disk format of disk /dev/nvme1n1: exit status 127`

**What you expected to happen?**
I expect that the volume will be mounted properly, as it is getting attached fine to the eks worker node and is properly formated as ext4.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)?**
Deploy a simple redis app in a kubernetes cluster, using gp2 storageclass as a volume provisioner and the ebs csi plugin and describe the redis pod, which should be stuck on ContainerCreate phase.

**Anything else we need to know?**:
I have set up IAM roles, policies and permissions as described in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html)
No volume encryption exists.
I have tried both the helm version and the AWS Console version just in case.
I assume it's maybe somehow related to the arm arch, as i have another envs with similar configurations, except the arch.
Any clues are greatly appreciated !

**Environment**

- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):
  1.23 / 1.24 / 1.25 / 1.26 - tried them all
  EKS workers are A family, so they are arm64 arch
- Driver version:
  v1.23.1-eksbuild.1

I haven't tried anything, as i have no clue what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EKS with a1 family has issues with recent CSI driver version, but v1.21.0-eksbuild.1 works fine with them.
Maybe older too, but haven't tried.